# Typescript "Can not resolve directory @angular"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs, jspm

So, I've got an error **"Can not resolve directory @angular"** in PHPStorm.

**Note:** I'm using Systemjs and JSPM for frontend dependencies.

Although, application works fine, but these error are really annoying. Basically, in **.js** files I'm not getting such an error, but in all **.ts** files this error occurs.

Here is screenshot of **main.ts** file:

[image]

Comment: Is everything working properly in your app or is there any error? "works fine" doens't necessarely mean that everything is working properly

Comment: I don't get any errors. All of files fetching with 200. For example, ``XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:4000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.1.js".``

Comment: did you check this already? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/typescript-support.html

Comment: I don't think this is a problem. WHen I installed angular-seed, for example,  [this one](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted) everything importing fine. Maybe problem with jspm or systemjs configuration?

Comment: Ooooh okay, so you're using JSPM. The problem, in my opinion, is probably related to the fact that the typescript module resolutor looks for NPM modules, not JSPM packages (check this for reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6012). Try to backup your `tsconfig.json` and set baseURL to jspm packages under `compilerOptions` (in tsconfig.json) `"baseUrl": "./jspm_packages"`. Also, add in the `exclude` the `jspm_packages`: `"exclude": [ "node_modules, "jspm_packages"]`

Comment: Good point, however it didn't help.

Comment: Try checking every possible typescript configuration available, it may also be necessary to actually tell PHPStorm that it needs to check for JSPM modules aswell.